# 'idiot smile' vs. 'idiotic smile', idiomaticity and usage

Tags: word-choice

I observed that 'idiot' is sometimes used as a modifier, which, as grammar.ccc says, '*are like teenagers: they fall in love with whatever they're next to. Make sure they're next to something they ought to modify!*'

Some instances of real English usage I found, among others, are the following:

> What kind of *idiot teenager* agrees to baby-sit on a millennial New Year's Eve, anyhow?
>
> They tried a plastic slide, but some *idiot teenager* broke it. Wood? It splinters as it ages.

Other than those there are a lot of other example, especially in reference to children, boys and girls.

So, I would like to know whether the English language has some limit in using 'idiot' as a modifier outside those cases.

I ask because I want to say that a friend of mine has an 'idiot smile', but after searching a bit I didn't find a lot of occurence of that expression and it seems that 'idiotic smile' is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fair question, and I don't think there's an easy answer. You must probably check for usage amongst friends and colleagues, on Google, and in a collocations dictionary. This is true for all 'attributive nouns': why a 'football manager' but rarely a 'badminton manager'? (probably because there aren't that many).

I remember the example in the Family d'Alembert series: *The Primary Computer Complex relayed instructions to the myriads of idiot versions of itself in preparation for the final battle against humanity* (not an accurate quote, but you get the picture). 'Idiotic' just wouldn't work here. I think 'idiot' focuses more on the agent or sub-agent (drone computers) being referenced, 'idiotic' on the behaviour. So, idiot teenager but idiotic smile / plan / decision / comment.